# Using datetime to compare two different timestamps?

Tags: python-datetime

Suppose I have two timestamps,

2023-09-09T04:18:22.676095594Z

2023-09-09T04:18:22.676Z

How does one compare them since they are of different lengths? Maybe I just want to compare the date, hours, minute, and seconds, and that's all. So I'd want just 2023-09-09T04:18:22 to be evaluated or concatenated to a list for instance.

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
for i in range(4):
  if date1 == date2:
     list.append(date2) #either or could work I think, since both are equal
  else:
      print("sorry no match")

date1 = 2023-09-09T04:18:22.676095594Z
date2 = 2023-09-09T04:18:22.676Z
```

Comment: Use [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()`

Example:

```py
from datetime import datetime

t1 = datetime.now()
t2 = datetime.now()
# t1: datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 13, 21, 40, 26, 524940)
# t2: datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 13, 21, 40, 26, 524950)

t1.replace(microsecond=0) == t2.replace(microsecond=0)
# True
```